# Vtiger : Outlook Plugin for Linux

Tags: vtiger

I use Linux os (ubuntu).I found that Outlook Plugin in vtiger can be installed only in windows.How can I install Outlook Plugin in my Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Vtiger Outlook Plugin is an .exe file which can't be installed in Unix Operating system. We need to wait till they implement some thing to support Linux.